# Javascript, then method not waiting for async function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set the background of my React App to the NASA APOD (Astronomy Picture of the Day). Here is my code for that:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_NASA_KEY;

function App() {
  const [bg, setBg] = useState(null);

  async function fetchPhoto() {
    const dat = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}`);
    const data = await dat.json();
    setBg(data); 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPhoto().then(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${bg.url}')`
    })
  }, [])

  return null;
}
```

However, in this code `then` does not wait for the state to be set and I get the error:

```
App.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'url')at App.js:22:1
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you returning `null` from that component, and why are you trying to set the document body background directly? React has a very different method of updating the DOM.

Comment: I'm returning null for now because App currently doesn't add anything to the dom and throws an error unless you return something; and the error suggests returning null if not rendering anything new. How would you set the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. Solution

A simpler way to achieve what you want is by doing like below, this way you don't have to menage asynchronous tasks like you are doing:

```js
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_NASA_KEY;

function App() {
  const [bg, setBg] = useState(null);

  async function fetchPhoto() {
    const dat = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}`);
    const data = await dat.json();
    setBg(data); 
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPhoto()
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(bg){
      document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${bg.url}')`;
    }
  }, [bg])

  return null;
}
```

### 2. Explanation

Your code is not working because just after `fetchPhoto()` is executed and resolved, React did not yet re-render the components (update the state), therefore `bg` is still `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround have my upvote, I'll use this for now but I'd still like to know why `then` isnt waiting / working how I thought it would

Comment: Thanks @Sujio, I added explanation below my answer. Take a look please !

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Thank you. I'll accept answer in 2 mins

Comment: `React did not yet re-render the components (update the state), therefore bg is still null.` This implies it's a problem with timing, but it's not. No matter how much time passes, `bg` will always be null. It's a local const and can never change.

Comment: @NicholasTower `bg` is a state, I don't get your point.

Comment: I'm saying that the explanation they gave is wrong. The solution is fine though.

Comment: Yeah I get that, I was asking how `bg` is a local const (to what) and why it would never change.

Comment: It's a local const because you wrote code `const [bg // etc`. As a `const`, it's value can never change. Even if you had used `let`, none of your code even attempts to change its value. Calling `setBg` does not change the value in `bg`. The purpose of calling `setBg` is to ask react to render the component again. That new render will have its own set of local variables, potentially with new values, but code from your old render has no access to those future local variables. Your code closes over the current variables only.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure either why state is declared as `const` and is able to change, but the most basic useState example from the react documentation uses `const` so I've just been following that: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @Sujio using `const` for this is good /thumbsup

Comment: @Sujio it is ok (even a good practice) to have your states as `const`. @NicholasTower I am in no way saying otherwise in my explanation, sorry that it makes you think it implies what you said in your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the state for something else? If not, you could avoid it:

```
function App() {
    
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPhoto = async () => {
      const dat = await fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=${apiKey}`);
      const data = await dat.json();
    
      if (data) {
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = `url('${data.url}')`;
      }
    }

    fetchPhoto();
  }, [])

  return null;
}
```